# How can I make a minute-interval timer in react-native without interrupting the rest of the code

Tags: react-native, timer

I need some help with logic for timer system

Summary of my case:
I work as a filling manager at a store, the employees have to fill the shelves after closing time. All of our goods are delivered on containers. I get a list of these containers and all of these containers have a time (in minutes) that it takes to complete them (fill all of it's content into the shelves).

That is my part-time job. I'm a college programming student as well.

I'm trying to develop an app (in react native) on which I can track the progress of these containers.

Now I have a few ideas on how to show the amount of time there's left until the container has to be finished but I feel like they're very inefficient in terms of performance

Idea 1:
Use a loop
    I simply create a (while) loop with a one
    second delay, it then checks the current time
    (hh:mm) and if one minute has passed it
    changes the time-left values of the containers.
    However this brings an issue: a while loop 
    like this is bad practice (?)

Idea 2:
Self calling function with a time-out
    I could make a method that calls itself every
    minute and then use this function multiple
    times, one for every container in progress.
    I could use a Boolean to interrupt it.
    But this also doesn't seem as a great practice

Idea 3:
System time trigger
    I have no clue on how I can actually make this, 
    I can't find anything online on this either.
    What I mean is a function that gets triggered
    by a change in the phone's system time.
    So that every minute that passes a function
    gets triggered and updates the time-left of
    all the containers

I have no clue which of these three ideas would be best.

If you have any other (better) idea on how I could tackle this problem I'm also open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use 'react-native-timer' (Can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-timer))

I call a method on an interval of 10s

```
Timer.setInterval('updateActiveContainerTimes', this.updateActiveContainerTimes, 10000)
```

and then in updateActiveContainerTimes I set the timeLeft variable like this:

```
container.timeLeft = container.time - this.getTimeDifference(container.startTime, new Date())
```

where getTimeDifference is a simple method that compares two date objects like this:

```
getTimeDifference(d1: Date, d2: Date) {
  let hourDifference = d2.getHours() - d1.getHours()
  let minuteDifference = d2.getMinutes() - d1.getMinutes()
  return (hourDifference * 60) + minuteDifference
}
```